# Excel - look for value in column then count number of occurrences in corresponding row

Tags: excel-formula

I have two sheets that both share the same unique identifier (listed in a column). Sheet 1 contains the raw data and on sheet 2 I am extracting key figures and making calculations.

In sheet 2 I would like to add a count of the number of times a word, say "Apple", appears in sheet 1 in the row that corresponds to the same ID. So it's a formula looking up the ID in sheet 1 and then counting the number of times "Apple" appears in that row.

I couldn't find a solution to this anywhere, so I would be grateful for any help!

Comment: Can you share an example of your data?

Comment: Thank you zipa, A.S.H has already provided me with the solution.

Comment: Still. This is properly good for future reference. It's better to put the data on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this formula:

```
=COUNTIF(OFFSET(Sheet1!$1:$1, MATCH(A1,Sheet1!A:A,0)-1, 0), "*Apple*")
```

This supposes your ID column in sheet2 is column A, it will count the occurrences of *Apple* where the row matches the id in sheet1 cell A1. You can type it at any cell in first row and copy down in the column.

Also, if you want to match whole cell content for "Apple", you can remove the wildcards from `"*Apple*"`.

Comment: Thank you very much, that did the trick! I was way off trying to combine countif with index match...